# Dropbox GUI not running on centos 7

Tags: dropbox, gui, centos-7

I am trying to install dropbox on my centos 7 system with Gnome by running

```
sudo rpm -ivh nautilus-dropbox-2015.10.28-1.fedora.x86_64.rpm
```

I don't know how to start the GUI afterwards, and the icon in the tray bar is not appearing.
I also tried installing the daemon:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -


~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Dropbox is syncing correctly, I just cannot open the GUI to define certain settings, e.g. selective sync.

Comment: Do you have a desktop environment installed in Cent? Which one?

Comment: OK. So `nautilus` is your default file manager and the Dropbox rpm package seems to be the correct one (it also install any dependencies, namely the daemon). You should just need to search "Dropbox" in apps and click to run it.

Comment: That's what I am doing, but nothing happens when I click it...

Comment: Please check you `/home/user` folder and if you find there a Dropbox folder then it's working and probably syncing. The indicator not appearing in the tray is then a different problem. I've heard that some "legacy" apps do not show their indicators unless specific support for that has been enabled in Gnome. So, I suggest googling that.

Comment: Dropbox is indeed syncing correctly, it's just the GUI, that is not working, which I would like to have in order to specify certain options.

Comment: I would try this https://askubuntu.com/a/597768 (yes, it's for Ubuntu but it's more related to Gnome than the OS where it's running). And this https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Installation-and-desktop-app/Gnome-3-28-Fedora-28-linux-Opening-file-manager-from-the-tray/td-p/275757 is probably more relevant to CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
sudo yum install libappindicator
```

And setting Tweak Tool>Extensions>Top icons on and applications menu on 
solved the problem